# Grails groovy application for websevices

Tags: grails, groovy

I have an employee services hosted, the client jar is availabe in my lib and I need to hit the employee service methods.

I need to develop a web app using grails and groovy.

I have done some web apps in grails but I'm not able to figure out on how to go with web serices call.

Where should I place this service call related code: In controller, service?

After I get the response I need to show them in UI and some inserts to db via hiberante.

Please suggets me.

Comment: Please try to pay a little more attention to your spelling as you have many scrambled letters that have nothing to do with knowing a language but making an efford.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule you should to try to keep your controllers as slim as possible.  You should probably put that code in a service class.

Simple Service class example:

```
class WebServiceService {
    def getEmployeeData(id) {
        // Read record and/or update domain objects
    }
}
```

Simple Controller example:

```
class EmployeeController {
    def webServiceService

    def view = {
        def employee = webServiceService.getEmployeeData(params.id)
        [employee: employee]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you mootinator
one small question. will name be WebServiceService.groovy or .java

Comment: .groovy will work just fine. Accessing java classes from Groovy is seamless.